# How do you scrape data from a website that keeps changing its class names and html layout python selenium and fanduell

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

## How do you scrape data from a website that keeps changing its class names and html layout python selenium

### Context

Im trying to scrape data from fanduel

[Example page](https://sportsbook.fanduel.com/basketball/wnba/connecticut-sun-@-indiana-fever-31588438)

The data im trying to get is the Spread, MoneyLine & Score, Game Clock

### Issue

The issue is every time you refresh the page the html layout and probably eventually the class names change

Example

- XPATH on refresh one: `//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div`
- XPATH on refresh two: `//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div`
- XPATH on refresh three: `//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div`

NOTE: that xpath is the same close button that hides and shows different sections about the game.

as you can see it's very annoying.

### What i've tried

I've tried researching this issue but nothing really came up and I'm just really frustrated if you know anything please let me know

### What is my end goal

I just want to be able to get the data I want automatically without user modification to the script.

Comment: Required data comes from XHR, so you can get it as JSON with direct POST-request to https://smp.nj.sportsbook.fanduel.com/api/sports/fixedodds/readonly/v1/getMarketPrices?priceHistory=1. However it won't be simple :)

Comment: @JaSON Can you show me an example of the request body idk what to put in it

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'X-Application': 'FhMFpcPWXMeyZxOx',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    'Origin': 'https://sportsbook.fanduel.com',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://sportsbook.fanduel.com/',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site',
}

params = {
    'priceHistory': '1',
}

json_data = {
    'marketIds': [
        '734.38192997',
        '734.38192998',
        '734.38193033',
        '734.38193034',
    ],
}

response = requests.post('https://smp.nj.sportsbook.fanduel.com/api/sports/fixedodds/readonly/v1/getMarketPrices', params=params, headers=headers, json=json_data)
response.json()
```

But watch out for the marketIds, they change as well. You may not need all of the header entries, and some of the values may not be valid in the future.
The marketIds are available in the network tab of your browser.
I assuming you can find them in the page html somewhere as well
[image: Network Request tab]

This information can be found in this network call:
[image: call for marketids]

Comment: What are the market ids and how do I get more if they expire

Comment: do you know if theres a way to grab that information with a script

Comment: I can see the url from where this info comes.
https://sbapi.nj.sportsbook.fanduel.com/api/event-page?betexRegion=GBR&capiJurisdiction=intl&currencyCode=USD&exchangeLocale=en_US&includePrices=true&language=en&priceHistory=1&regionCode=NAMERICA&_ak=FhMFpcPWXMeyZxOx&eventId=31588438&tab=popular

Answer (score -1):

You can try to get data with this code:

```
score_team_1 = driver.find_element('xpath', '//div[starts-with(@aria-label, "current score")]/span').text
score_team_2 = driver.find_element('xpath', '(//div[starts-with(@aria-label, "current score")])[2]/span').text

game_time = driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[name()="title" and .="live event"]/following::div/span').text

spread_team_1 = driver.find_element('xpath', '(//div[@role="button" and (span or *[name()="svg"])])[1]/span').text
spread_team_2 = driver.find_element('xpath', '(//div[@role="button" and (span or *[name()="svg"])])[4]/span').text

money_team_1 = driver.find_element('xpath', '(//div[@role="button" and (span or *[name()="svg"])])[2]/span').text
money_team_2 = driver.find_element('xpath', '(//div[@role="button" and (span or *[name()="svg"])])[5]/span').text

print("The score is {0} : {1}".format(score_team_1, score_team_2))
print("The spreads are: {0} / {1}".format(spread_team_1, spread_team_2))
print("The game time is {}".format(game_time))
print("The money indicators are: {0} / {1}".format(money_team_1, money_team_2))
```

Note that sometimes values are locked, so instead of text locked image displayed instead so you need to implement try/except blocks

Comment: Yo i actually love you for this but game time doesn't work for me :( im using a chrome extension to view the xpath and it just selects a bunch of things so its incorrect. but everything else worked with some needing slightly different values

Comment: Hey JaSON is their a way I could contact you outside of here, because if possible I have something else I need to scrape from the same site and I would want to pay you for it maybe like $5-$10 but just let me know

Comment: @Caminero just raise another question here, on SO, and I'll try to help